# ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: TCPServer not defined Julia

Tags: julia

the following is the code.

```
using JEMSS
# println(2+3)
filename = selectXmlFile()
sim = initSim(filename);

simulate!(sim) # run the simulation
printSimStats(sim) # some basic statistics
```

while I'm running this, I got the following error message:

```
[ Info: Precompiling JEMSS [24979329-2a3d-50cf-82e3-05af2f1830ac]
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `@doc call with ->` at /Users/jack/.julia/packages/HttpServer/ZGldt/src/HttpServer.jl:229.
│ Use `a line break` instead.
└ @ ~/.julia/packages/HttpServer/ZGldt/src/HttpServer.jl:229
WARNING: importing deprecated binding Base.listen into HttpServer.
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: TCPServer not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./sysimg.jl:13
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [6] top-level scope at none:2
 [7] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [8] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:399
 [9] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/nanal/.julia/packages/HttpServer/ZGldt/src/HttpServer.jl:31
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile HttpServer [58cfbd8c-6b7d-5447-85c1-563540e28d27] to /Users/jack/.julia/compiled/v0.7/HttpServer/SC4ql.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:313 [inlined]
 [3] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1185
 [4] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./logging.jl:311
 [5] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:852
 [6] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
 [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:834
 [8] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [10] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [11] top-level scope at none:2
 [12] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [13] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:399
 [14] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/jack/.julia/dev/JEMSS/src/JEMSS.jl:20
```

I was trying to search to find out what exactly is this `"ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: TCPServer not defined"`, but I can not find any. Can anyone please tell me where I can find any references for it? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, maybe you are using Julia 0.7/1.0? It seems that JEMSS.jl supports unfortunatly only Julia 0.6. You can see their [CI status](https://travis-ci.com/uoa-ems-research/JEMSS.jl) and find that nightly builds fail.

Comment: I tried Julia 0.6. But for Julia 0.6, I can not even do the three Pkg.clone  as required by the git link...... sigh